# Open saved matlab .fig as specific figure number

Tags: matlab, maps, fig

For my workflow, I am continually updating a set of figures that provide information on the current status of a remotely operated underwater glider. I have these figures arranged on my desktop so I can view all of them at once to assess the glider's status. When I update them, I don't want to create a new figure every time (and end up with a million figures that are nearly identical), so I have assigned each of the specific figure types a number and I just clear them (with `clf`) before regenerating after each surfacing and communication with the glider.

For my mapping figure, the basemap showing detailed bathymetry is quite large. With my current approach, I have to replot the bathymetry and contour lines each time, which is very slow and memory intensive. I would like to save the bathymetry and contour lines as a "basemap.fig" that I can load more quickly. Then, I can overlay the latest location data on the basemap.

I run this script 2-3 times a day, for two different gliders, for 8 weeks, so inevitably I do have to reboot my computer sometimes in between. I would like to save the basemap as a .fig (rather than just plot it once and hold it as a handle in the workspace) because it can take 30+ minutes to generate the contours each time (and piloting the gliders can be time sensitive so if IT rebooted my computer in the night, I can't always be waiting 30+ minutes to load a map; also, no, I can't get IT to not reboot).

However, if I load basemap.fig using `openfig`, it creates a NEW figure. This then has the potential to leave me with many many figures, each just slightly different, being created each time I run the processing script. I realize this isn't the end of the world, but I am also creating many other control figures and my desktop gets cluttered very quickly.

So, my question is -
**Is there a way to open a saved .fig file as a specific figure number?**

Here is my minimum reproducible example. Note, this does require the mapping toolbox. I am not sure the issue I'm having is mapping toolbox dependent but because I know the way axes work is a bit different with the mapping toolbox I wanted to use that in this example.

```
% SET UP 
% set my figure number
figNum = 100; % target figure number
% want to continually overwrite this figure, keeping it in this spot, as I
% get updated track data
 

% CREATE BASEMAP FIGURE
% this is the slow step so I want to make this once, save it, and reload it
% when I want to replot. 
baseFig = figure(figNum); % I don't think assigning the number here matters
ax = axesm('mercator', 'MapLatLim', [19.0 22.75], 'MapLonLim', [-160.0 -154.25]);
states = shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(states);
savefig('baseFigFile.fig');

% LOAD BASEMAP AND ADD TO IT
% this is where I want it to consistently be the same figure number
mapFig = figure(figNum);
% open the existing figure that was saved as a .fig file
mapFig = openfig('baseFigFile.fig'); % where baseFig is a fullfile path and filename to the saved .fig
% add some data to the baseFig
plotm([19.4; 20.5], [-156.5; -157.5]); 
textm([19.4; 20.5], [-156.5; -157.5], {'LW01'; 'LW02'});
```

As I have it now, when I load the saved baseMapFile.fig, it just opens as a new figure (sequentially from 1, not replacing any existing figures).

**EDIT**
I realize now this is very much an XY problem and that the solution may not be in opening a .fig file and assigning it to a specific figure number.

So, my revised, broader question is - how can I load a .fig file (containing a basemap that takes a long time to create so needs to be saved) and then plot new data on that same axis, without cluttering my desktop with new, ever so slightly different figures, each time I run it?

Comment: Does something like [this](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/520814-how-can-i-give-a-figure-both-a-name-and-a-number) help? You can change the number after you create the figure.

Comment: I don't think so. I have tried to change the figure number after loading the baseFig (used a handle so `mapFig = openfig(baseFig)` and this still opens a new figure (with new number). If I try to re-number (`mapFig.Number = 100`) gives the error: You cannot set the read-only property 'Number' of Figure.

Comment: I think using handles might be what I need to do (as suggested by the link you shared) but still can't seem to get it to work how I want it to.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]? This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I agree you want to use figure handles instead of figure numbers, but it's hard to grasp what you're saving/loading vs what you want to plot on top, can you distil the question down to a couple of random-data plots and how they should interact in this workflow?

Comment: Updated as requested @Wolfie please let me know if you need more than that! After working on this for the last 24 hours, my current work around is just to save all the pieces that go into the basemap (e.g., states in the above example) as a .mat file, load that .mat file, and replot all of them in the numbered figure of my choosing. Not elegant but for now it is working and is still faster than creating contours on every iteration.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the same figure number here... Can't you just omit the two lines before `openfig`? And then if you want to set the loaded `mapFig` to be your new base, you can use `baseFig = figure(mapFig)` instead of `baseFig = figure(figNum)`?

Comment: I'd like to use the same figure number because I am repeatedly re-making this figure as I get updated data files in near real time and I don't want to end up with lots and lots of figures crowding my desktop. I just want to overwrite the existing one with new data
`baseFig` is created in a separate function (it's VERY SLOW) that's why I want to save it, then re-open it as needed, and not have to always recreate it.

Comment: So, ignoring figure numbers for a second because they're only one of several ways to reference a figure object, you want to be able to use `openfig` to reincarnate an old figure, but have that appear in a specific figure window which already exists? What should happen to all existing stuff in that figure window, can we assume it's empty? Is there any issue with recording the position of the old figure window, closing it, opening the saved figure, setting the position to be the same as it was, and plotting on the new figure going forwards?

Comment: All existing stuff in the existing figure window will be cleared before replotting (unless there is a way to just remove a subset of plotted objects in an existing figure, but leave others?) I could potentially close the old figure, open the saved figure, and plot the new stuff in the saved figure, but this wouldn't necessarily always be the same figure number so I'd need to figure a way to close that specific figure only (as there are several other figures I want to keep open and that number may change).

Comment: It's still hard for me to visualise what you're trying to do, maybe I'm being dense. Yes you can just remove some plotted components from a figure, either by retaining variables of their object handles (i.e. `p = plot( ____ );`) or finding the handles later (e.g. using `findobj`) then `delete(p)`. Maybe you could even use `copyobj` to load the saved plot, copy the graphics to your target figure, then close the saved plot. It would help if your [mcve] was in fact _minimal_, currently there's lots of irrelevant clutter, can you demonstrate the goal with images and very simple plots in an [edit]?

Comment: This question is an XY Problem, as Wolfie said. The answer to your question is "No, there is not a way to open a figure from a saved file and assign a specific figure number to the resulting figure window". But that is not what you really care about, is it? :) See my answer.

Comment: As an FYI...I came up with a solution that helps speed things up but does not do exactly what I previously was asking. I just saved the loaded/modified raster and contours that I was creating in the basefig, saved them as a .mat file, and loaded that .mat in the function I have to plot the new fig. 

I did experiment a bunch with `copyobj` but after copying to a new figure, could not get any additional data to plot.

Comment: In that case I would use [gca](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html); see the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You need a paradigm shift to get to the solution you want-** its not the *figure* you want to update, it is the *axis* in the figure window. In Matlab, the "figure", created by the `figure` command, is just a window:

```
>> figure
```

[image: figure window]

It is the axis in the figure window where plots are created.

```
>> axes
```

[image: figure window with axis]

So the axis and the figure are not the same- you could have multiple axes in the same window (the [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) command does this), you could destroy the axis without closing the figure, etc.

This can be confusing because the basic [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command does three things for you automatically: creates a figure window, creates an axes in the figure, and draws your data lines on it. That is convenient when you just need a plot, but if you want to do more sophisticated graphics operations, you need to understand the different graphics components.

Also, it will be helpful to internalize the concept of [graphics *handles*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/how-to-work-with-graphics-objects.html): a variable that is a reference to an object. So the handle to a figure window is the variable that specifies a figure (not the figure number); the handle to an axis is the way to specify an axis when you want to add a plot to it, etc.

So, to update a complex data plot repeatedly, use a handle to the *axis* to make updates. At a high level, this looks like:

1. create a figure
2. create an axis on the figure, and save the handle to that axis
3. draw whatever you want in the axis for the initial set up
4. set a "hold" on the axis
5. make updates to the plot by drawing more data on the axis as needed

For example:

```
% 1) create figure window
figure;
% 2) create axis for the plot and save handle
hax = axes;
% 3) put initial data on the plot
plot(hax,[0 1],[0.5 0.5],'-k','LineWidth',3)
title(hax,'Complex Data Plot- Set Up')
xlabel(hax,'My X Label')
ylabel(hax,'My Y Data')
grid(hax,'on')
% 4) hold the plot on the axis
hold(hax,'on')

% 5) update the plot as needed
for k=1:10
    disp('Press any key to update the plot...')
    pause();
    plot(hax,[rand rand],[rand rand],'--r')
    title(hax,sprintf('Complex Data Plot- Update #%d',k))
end
disp('done.')
```

Note that all the commands here specify the axis handle (`hax`) explicitly. In most examples in the documentation, this is left out, because all of the Matlab functions assume you are working with only one plot at a time.

This example uses simple plot operations; the [`plotm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/plotm.html) command from the Mapping Toolbox is the equivalent of `plot`, so the same concepts apply.

Another helpful graphics handle function is [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html), this will return the handle to the current axes. So, if you open a figure file that was saved to disk, and you want to get the axis handle so you can use the techniques discussed above, you can do:

```
% after the file is saved, you close and restart matlab,
%  then open the file from disk
bMapFig = openfig('map.fig');
hax = gca; % get the handle to the current axis
% continue with operations that update the plot
```

Comment: Thanks @mhopeng and @wolfie for hanging with me on this! I see how I've fallen into the XY trap here. 

I see this approach with the handles and that does make sense, but if I were to want to shut down my computer in between, could I save `hax` as a .mat file and replot hax within a new figure?

Comment: If shutting down the computer is important, you should include that in your question (and are there any other surprise requirements?)

Comment: I'm trying to overhaul the question now that I understand a bit more what any XY question is...one second!

Comment: In any case yes, the same approach applies. Load the figure with `hMapFig = openfig('baseFigFile.fig')`, then use `hax = gca` to get a handle to the axis with the map in it. Remember handles are just a way to refer to an object, they are not the actual object.

Comment: I added a link to the Matlab doc page for [graphics handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/how-to-work-with-graphics-objects.html).

Comment: No worries; specifying the problem is usually the hardest part of finding the solution ;)